# Calculating Modified V5 Dice Probabilities with AnyDice

Tags: world-of-darkness, statistics, dice, anydice

My game uses 5th edition rules with a house rule where 1s subtract successes and 10s count as two successes. 2s through 5s count as no successes and 6s through 9s count as single successes as normal.

I'd like to compare the specific probability ranges to V5's normal rules. What function can I use to do so over AnyDice?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: And what are the “normal rules” so people who don’t play the game but know about anydice can help?

Comment: Dice are d10s. If you roll above a certain value, you get a success. Characters roll (typically) 1 to 10 dice, known as "pools," for attempted actions. The more successes you roll, the better. 

Otherwise, as described above. A die result of 2-5 adds no successes. A result of 6-9 adds a single successes. A result of 10 adds two successes, and a result of 1 takes away one success. If you roll one or more 1s and no successes, it's possible to go into negatives.

Comment: The normal rules are that results of 1-5 add no successes, results of 6-10 count as one success, and if you roll two 10s, they each count as two successes. Rolling a single 10 still counts as just one success.

Comment: @FalseEpiphany what happens if you roll three 10s (normal rules)? You mention rolling one 10 counts as one success, two 10s counts as four successes. What about three or more 10s?

Comment: 10s only double if you roll them in pairs. So if you roll two 10s, you get four successes. If you roll four 10s, you get eight successes. But if you roll three 10s, you get five successes. Five 10s likewise get you nine successes. 

It's an overly fiddly mechanic for my taste. There's a reason I chose just to make all 10s count as two successes.

Comment: @FalseEpiphany So, in V5 normal rules, botches are impossible? The lowest score is zero, but never negative?

Comment: Under both systems, a botch happens if you roll no successes. A failure happens if you roll fewer successes than an attempted action's difficulty. Under the house rules, how many negatives you get doesn't matter. A botch is a botch.

Comment: Then I will alter my answer.

Comment: Oh, not sure I explained it clearly. Under both systems, you get a botch if you roll no successes. Under V5's original rules, 1s don't subtract successes. That's unique to my house rules. Does that still alter your answer?

Comment: @FalseEpiphany I think I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short mock up of code to compare the two. wodvfive is the original rules and wodcustom is your new rules.

```
function: wodvfive roll COUNT:n dice {
  RELABELED: {1, 2:4, 9:4, 10}
  result: [wodvfive roll COUNT d RELABELED]
}

function: wodvfive roll ROLL:s {
  
  SUPERSUCCESSES: [count {10} in ROLL]
  SUCCESSES: [count {9} in ROLL]
  BOTCHES: [count {1} in ROLL]

  if (SUCCESSES+SUPERSUCCESSES = 0) & BOTCHES > 0 {
    result: -1
  }
  else
  {
    result: SUCCESSES+SUPERSUCCESSES+2*(SUPERSUCCESSES/2)
  }

}

function: wodcustom roll COUNT:n dice {
  RELABELED: {1,2:4,9:4,10}
  result: [wodcustom roll COUNT d RELABELED]
}

function: wodcustom roll ROLL:s {
  SUPERSUCCESSES: [count {10} in ROLL]
  SUCCESSES: [count {9} in ROLL]
  BOTCHES: [count {1} in ROLL]

  TOTALSUCCESSES: SUCCESSES+2*SUPERSUCCESSES-BOTCHES

  if TOTALSUCCESSES < 0 {
    if SUCCESSES+SUPERSUCCESSES = 0 {
      result: -1
    }
    else {
      result: 0
    }
  }
  else {
    result: TOTALSUCCESSES
  }
}

output [wodvfive roll 3 dice]
output [wodcustom roll 3 dice]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that does exactly what I wanted!

Comment: So, interesting results, looking the two systems over. At 3 dice, my rules result in a slightly higher success baseline and slightly lower success maximum. At 10 dice, my rules result in a moderately lower success baseline and pretty much the same success maximum. At 7 dice, my rules result in a moderately lower baseline and marginally earlier maximum. 

It looks like the original rules are the better ones for PCs. Since I also have more generous Willpower rules, I'll probably call things even. I'd been deliberating whether to change things there or not. 

Thanks again!

Comment: @FalseEpiphany I updated the functions with the new information you provided about botches.